# conditionally include else clause the C++ way

Tags: templates, c++11

I have a member function that has various statements being printed for debugging purposes.  `solve<true>()` should print them all, and `solve<false>()` should not.

```
template <bool print>
void solve() {
    // do a bunch of setup and computations...
    if(print) {// this works as you would expect
        cout << "statistics on various items" << endl;
    }
    // do some more stuff
    for(things i have to do) {
        if(methodCall()) {

        }
        // !!! this is the question !!!
        if(print) {// clearly this isn't valid syntax
        else {
            cout << "only compile else on print=true" << endl;
        }
        }// if(print) end...
    }
}
```

So basically, `methodCall()` returns a boolean, and when it is `false` I don't want to even have the `else` clause when the template `bool` is `false`.  I understand that I could do

```
if(print) {
    if(methodCall()) {
        /// ...
    }
    else {
        /// print stats
    }
}
else {
    if(methodCall()) {
        /// ...
    }
}
```

but this will be highly error prone because the code in `/// ...` is massive and actively being changed.  Likewise, I am avoiding template specialization like the plague here...I need exactly one version of the code to avoid copy-paste errors or out-of-sync updates.  The stuff inside `if(methodCall())` isn't working, and that's why I'm doing this ;)

If I were doing the C way I would do

```
if(methodCall()) {
    /// ...
}
#ifdef PRINT_STATS
else {
    cout << "stats" << endl;
}
#endif
```

but I feel like there already exists a C++ alternative.

If this isn't possible, are there alternatives?  Thanks!

Comment: There is already a suggestion for that: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3613.pdf

Comment: @MarianSpanik: That's a three year old proposal that didn't go anywhere.

Comment: Note that the `if (print)` part is **compiled** even if `print==false`. This means the code has to be logically correct. E.g. if you have a template parameter `int N` you can't write `if (N>0) { char buf[N]; /***/ }` . Sure, the code is unreachable for `N==0` but it still has to compile. So you get workarounds as `if (N>0) { char buf[(N>0) ? N : 1]; /***/ }`

Comment: @MSalters: you definitely seem to know a lot about this based off this and the below comment.  While I understand the "no real `else if`" statement, this comment confuses me wrt to the `if(print)`.  My understanding of how these get compiled down (in the `bool` case) is that two different code paths can ultimately be generated.  When you have the `if(false)` case, is it not reasonable to assume that most compilers will simply omit that code block altogether?  I think what you are saying is it is important to distinguish between _unreachable_ code and _nonexistent_ code (at execution time)?

Comment: @sjm324 : It tends to be removed by the optimizer, but the compiler still needs to process it - if only to find the end ! That's only compile time, though.

Comment: fair enough, thanks for explaining all this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do :

```
for(things i have to do) {
    if(methodCall()) {

    }
    else if(print) {
            cout << "only compile else on print=true" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: haha WOW that's pretty obvious. it works and I've accepted it, it would be interesting to see if this is actually possible to do though ;) Or would this always be logically equivalent to an `else` even if there are other `else if` statements?

Comment: @sjm324: There's actually no such thing as an `else if` statement. The `else` part belongs to the previous if-statement. So it's logically `if (x)... else { if (y) ... }`, a second nested `if` statement. You can always add a `if (print)` to any block of code, including an `else` block.

Answer (score 2):

One easy workaround is to have a specialized helper template.

```
template <bool print> void log() {
   std::cout << "statistics on various items" << std::endl;
}

template <> void log<false> () { }

template <bool print>
void solve() {
    // do a bunch of setup and computations...
    log<print>();
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is still a place for macros even in modern C++ and personally I think this is one of them. If is very standard practice to define macros that specify  whether or not you're in 'debug mode'.

Maybe this is just a personal preference, but I feel it is inappropriate to use a template parameter for this purpose. The parameter says nothing about how the function is evaluated or its effect on program state - only whether debug statements should be printed. This somehow isn't the 'spirit' of templates.

Comment: Yeah I have to agree it's a bit awkward, but a macro is significantly less convenient for my purposes.  The short version is that whether or not stats are printed is determined by what is in the `xml` description of the scene.  Recompiling to test is more than reasonable, but this project takes ~20min to compile sometimes...

Comment: Fully agree with this.

Comment: Thanks @LightnessRacesinOrbit. Was afraid I might be hounded out of the room for that